# Как отследить, что произошел клик вне этого дива на чистом js без jquery

Tags: javascript

Если не затруднит, покажите пример рабочего кода. Как по клику, все окна, закрыть окно?

[Мой код](https://codepen.io/Teslenko/pen/pVPopp)

```js
let flagClose = true;
document.getElementById("widget").addEventListener("click", close);


function close() {
  if (flagClose) {
    document.getElementById("pulse").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("list").style.display = "block";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("pulse").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
  }
  flagClose = !flagClose;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fda600;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.widget-wrapper {
  z-index: 99999999999;
  right: 15%;
  top: 80%;
  position: fixed;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.pulse {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2cb743;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(44, 183, 67, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pulse:hover {
  animation: none;
}

.widget-list {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 450px;
  left: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -2px 99px -28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -2px 99px -28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 99px -28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: 1s;
}

.widget-list::after {
  content: '';
  width: 38px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(Hint-part.svg) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 40px;
}

.list-item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
}

.item-img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 150px;
}

.item-img_cont {
  background: url('Animation-icons.svg') no-repeat;
  background-color: #fda600;
  background-position: 14px center;
}

.item-img_msg {
  background: url('Animation-icons.svg') no-repeat;
  background-color: #0080e7;
  background-position: -64px center;
}

.item-img_wtapp {
  background: url('Animation-icons.svg') no-repeat;
  background-color: #00c246;
  background-position: -145px center;
}

.item-img_email {
  background: url('Animation-icons.svg') no-repeat;
  background-color: #00aaf6;
  background-position: -224px center;
}

.item-img_call {
  background: url('Animation-icons.svg') no-repeat;
  background-color: #00d76f;
  background-position: -304px center;
}

.list-item p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.list-item p a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #292929;
}

.wrapper-contant {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 8px auto;
}

.pusle-txt-block {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  -webkit-animation: pulsText 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.close {
  display: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #2cb743;
  border-radius: 150px;
  right: 15%;
  top: 80%;
  position: fixed;
}

.close:before,
.close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 39px;
  top: 23px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.pusle-txt-block::after {
  content: 'Get Help';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.row-bg-amimations {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url('Animation-icons.svg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 700%;
  background-position-y: center;
  animation: bgIcons 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(44, 183, 67, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(44, 183, 67, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(44, 183, 67, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(44, 183, 67, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(44, 183, 67, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(44, 183, 67, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(44, 183, 67, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(44, 183, 67, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(44, 183, 67, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulsText {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
}

@keyframes bgIcons {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 13px;
  }
  25% {
    background-position-x: -83px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position-x: -180px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position-x: -275px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: -370px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-wrapper" id="widget">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="pulse" id="pulse">
                <div class="wrapper-contant" id="wrapper">
                    <div class="pusle-txt-block" id="block"></div>
                </div>
            </span>
    <div class="close" id="close"></div>
    <ul class="widget-list" id="list" onclick="onDivClick(event);">
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="item-img item-img_cont"></div>
        <p><a href=""> Contact Support</a></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="item-img item-img_msg"></div>
        <p><a href=""> Messenger</a></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="item-img item-img_wtapp"></div>
        <p><a href="">WhatsApp</a></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="item-img item-img_email"></div>
        <p><a href=""> support@hostname.com</a></p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="item-img item-img_call"></div>
        <p><a href=""> Call Me Back</a></p>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: просто я намудрил и у меня вышло примерно вот так codepen.io/Teslenko/pen/pVPopp

Comment: нужно обработчик события повесить не на виджет, а на весь документ и потом проводить проверку - куда кликнул пользователь

Answer (score 1):

Это очень простой пример. Но мне одно интересно, в чем конкретно у вас возникла сложность, в чем проблема? ведь такие задачи гуглится легко =). Задайте более четкий вопрос, опишите по подробнее

```js
var block = document.getElementById('block');
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != 'block') {
    block.classList.add('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #555;
}

#block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: просто я намудрил и у меня вышло примерно вот так https://codepen.io/Teslenko/pen/pVPopp

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать [`Node#contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains):

```
// получили ссылку но DOM ноду, при клике вне которой ее нужно скрывать
const node = document.getElementById('my-node');
// обработчик события
function handleClick(event) {
  // если нода содержит в себе элемент, по которому произошел клик
  // или клик произошел по самой ноде - значит клик был "внутри" ноды
  //  => не делаем ничего
  if (node.contains(event.target)) return;
  // закрываем ноду
  closeNode();
}
// повесили событие на документ
document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```